Is there a way to change the dragHandle's size and padding in ModelBottomSheet from Material3 in Jetpack Compose?
I've encountered an issue when trying to use ModalBottomSheet() from Jetpack Compose, as the dragHandle is always visible, no matter what I do. Then I discovered this little surprise in the source file 'SheetDefaults.kt' that describe the drag handle's composable:
Surface(
            modifier = modifier
                .padding(vertical = DragHandleVerticalPadding)
                .semantics { contentDescription = dragHandleDescription },
            color = color,
            shape = shape
        )

On further inspection, the value DragHandleVerticalPadding is actually hardcoded at the end of this file...
private val DragHandleVerticalPadding = 22.dp.
Is there maybe a workaround for this issue, so that the dragHandle is no longer visible?
Thank you in advance.
I've tried changing the size manually of the drag handle and padding, by passing the modifier to the BottomSheetDefaults(), but then the height of the handle is somehow bigger than when just passing an empty curly braces for the dragHandle in ModalBottomSheet.
This is the code of ModalBottomSheet, with the usage of BottomSheetDefaults.DragHandle(...) and passing the modifier as an argument:
            ModalBottomSheet(
                onDismissRequest = {
                    playerViewModel.updateShowPlayer(false)
                },
                shape = RoundedCornerShape(0.dp),
                sheetState = sheetState,
                dragHandle = { BottomSheetDefaults.DragHandle(
                    modifier = Modifier.padding(0.dp),
                    width = 0.dp,
                    height = 0.dp,
                    color = Color.Transparent,
                    shape = RoundedCornerShape(0.dp)
                )},
                containerColor = Color(0xFF111111),
                contentColor = Color(0xFF111111),
                modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),

            ) {
                PlayerScreen(
//                modifier = Modifier.offset(y = offset.dp),
                    onClose = {
//                    playerViewModel.onClose()
                    },
                    isCurrent = true,
                    screenSize = 740.dp,
                    onDrag = {
//                    playerViewModel.onDrag(it)
                    }
                )
            }

This code results in bigger height of the drag handle than this approach:
dragHandle = {} // or dragHandle = null


I've found some workaround for this particular problem.
Firstly, I have added this line to the configuration:

WindowCompat.setDecorFitsSystemWindows(window, true)

Which makes the content of the application always fill the full screen, regardless of the system bar's padding. Then, (with the usage of dragHandle = { } or = null) I set:

containerColor = Color.Transparent.

The content of the ModalBottomSheet is now filling the entire screen, thanks to the WindowCompat line, and the leftover space that comes from the drag handle is now colliding with the status bar, so it practically is "hidden".
Hope this helps someone!

For me, either doing
dragHandle = null

or
dragHandle = {}

removes the drag handle and any padding.
I have the following dependencies set up:
implementation "androidx.compose.foundation:foundation:1.7.0-rc01"
implementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui:1.7.0-rc01"
implementation 'androidx.compose.material3:material3:1.3.0-rc01'

Output:

If you want then to properly place any content, just use the padding Modifier like this:
ModalBottomSheet(
    onDismissRequest = { },
    dragHandle = { }
) {
    Column(
        modifier = Modifier.padding(top = 32.dp, start = 16.dp, end = 16.dp)
    ) {
        Text(text = "HELLO\nWORLD")
    }
}

Output:


It does indeed remove the dragHandle, but doesn't remove the space on top of your Column

For me, there is no space left at the top after removing the dragHandle. Please see the first screenshot in my edited post.

That's strange. When I set the dragHandle to null, the space is still visible and no matter what I do, my content won't fill the whole sheet.

I edited my post and added the dependencies that I use. Can you please try to update your dependencies and then report back if the issue persists?

Those are mine dependencies:
implementation(libs.androidx.activity.compose)
implementation(platform(libs.androidx.compose.bom))
Maybe a little off topic, but shouldn't the direct approach in adding implementations from libs.* add the latest version of such library?

Even if it automatically picks the latest BOM version, the latest BOM version only contains stable library versions. Compose 1.7 brings huge refactorings and improvements, but only is in release channel and not stable yet. Please try to manually add the same dependencies that I have, then they will override what you have in BOM.
